# android: can 140 dpi will get mdpi resource?

Tags: android

In android docs, it is said that 140 still is ldpi, but when I change dpi to 140, I find mdpi resource is retrieved, can someone have idea? thanks a lot.

btw, I read the code about how to get resource, seems ldpi's max dpi value is 131.25? Does google post the wrong doc?

Answer (score 0):

The [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) say ldpi is for "for 100 to 140 dpi screens." and mdpi is for "140 to 180 dpi", which indicates 140 could be correctly reported as mdpi (to something does not necessarily mean that it includes that something).

The [compatibility test suite](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/cts.git;a=blob;f=tests/tests/dpi/src/android/dpi/cts/ConfigurationTest.java;h=c03600a8bfed70df161e188e9fdc6c4401fadae8;hb=b4f1a557657cdc7c0210ec9180b858bce28704b7) does, however, appear to indicate 140 should be classified as LDPI, so it's probably worth raising this in b.android.com as a bug stating the platform your running on.

Comment: thanks, i think it is resource bug which does not match this indicators.